# SQL Query for count of tags on Joomla

Tags: mysql, count, joomla

I need to get a count of all the articles in a Joomla install that use each tag on the tags table.

Is there a way to do that without writing a PHP script?

The tag field on the articles (_content) table comes as a comma separated field with the IDs of the tags on the _tags table.

I cant figure out a way to get the count using ONLY MySQL, any ideas??

Comment: What is your version of joomla you are using ?

Comment: We are using Joomla version 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, there's no tag field in the table `#_content` prior to joomla 3.4.x, and all recent joomla versions have a junction table `#_contentitem_tag_map`

Answer (score 0):

As Kolunar points out, there is no tag column on a standard Joomla install...

Turns out the Joomla I have to work with, its a modified/customized version of Joomla.

I ended up writing a small PHP script to get the count according to the custom column that was added to the content table.

Comment: I would be really dubious unless I understood how that was being recorded.